# Apache - Simple Alias directive not working

Tags: apache2

On Ubuntu server I have the following folder tree:
/var/www/domain
/var/www/camera

In .conf file for Apache I have:

```
ServerName domain.eu
ServerAlias www.domain.eu
DocumentRoot /var/www/domain
Alias /camera /var/www/camera
```

If the user types "www.domain.eu", it goes to /var/www/domain. It is ok.

But it doesn't work, if user types "www.domain.eu/camera" to redirect him to /var/www/camera.
User get: "The requested URL /camera was not found on this server."

Anything missing?

UPDATE:
My current configuration is next:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName      domain.eu
        ServerAlias     www.domain.eu
        <Directory "/var/www/domain">
                Options All Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/domain

        Alias /camera /var/www/camera
        <Directory "/var/www/camera">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog        ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog       ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. I still get "The requested URL /camera was not found on this server."

Comment: `www.domain.com/camera` or `www.domain.eu/camera` ? - What you mean with doesn't work : you get which error n#, any error log...

Comment: Sorry, I just edited a question (typo and add result in browser).

Comment: Since your alias is out of DocumentRoot, you need <Directory> directive. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048239/apache-alias-outside-of-virtual-host-document-route, and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056452/directory-alias-directory-outside-documentroot. And I am sure there are more answers available.

Comment: You have `Alias /kamera ...`, yet you try `example.org/camera`. Are you consistent?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Edited.

Comment: Please ensure that your configuration is consistent. Is what is above *really* what is running on the Apache server?

Comment: I would perhaps recommend you ask this question on a different Stack Exchange website. Either on https://serverfault.com/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ perhaps

Comment: @vidarlo: 
Yes, it is. The inconsistency was due to changing (only domain and folder) before publishing the question.

Comment: @Xweque: 
Ok, I will wait a little if someone gets any idea.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. 
Alias commands has to be configured in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf file. 
It is quite strange, but they are ignored in the virtual host files.
In my opinion, this isn't logical - if I have more websites, than an alias in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf will work for all websites. But it started working immediately after I moved alias from website config file to alias.conf file.